# custom keras metric for row accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a multi-label classification problem:
here are some examples of y:

```
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,0]
[1,0,0]
```

and so on. 
I would like to create a function that tells me the % of rows in the prediction that, based on 0.5 threshold, are equal to the true vector in y. 
so if y is:

```
[[0,0,1]
[1,0,0]
[1,0,1]]
```

and predictions are:

```
[[0.2,0.4,0.9]
[0.6,0.3,0.4]
[0.3,0.3,0.4]]
```

the accuracy is 2/3, since two rows predict the same labels and 1 is not.

this what I have right now:

```
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):

    acc = K.all(K.equal(y_true, y_pred), axis=1)
    acc= K.cast(acc, 'float32')
    acc = K.sum(acc)
    acc = acc/K.cast(K.shape(y_true)[0], 'float32')
    return acc
```

but it shows me the message during training and shows accuracy of 0:

```
Allocation of 223027200 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

the shapes of y_train and y_test are:
(1285, 3)
(551, 3)

the shape of X_train:
(1285, 70, 70, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution for anyone who needs it:

```
 def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):

        y_pred = K.round(y_pred)
        acc = K.all(K.equal(y_true, y_pred), axis=1)
        acc= K.cast(acc, 'float32')
        acc = K.sum(acc)
        acc = acc/K.cast(K.shape(y_true)[0], 'float32')
        return acc
```